# MongoDB in memory map-reduce, native mapReduce or aggregation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a collection called `collections`, which contains nested array of `items`.

```
{
    id: 1,
    items: [{id: 'a', val: 1}, {id: 'b', val: 1}, {id: 'c', val: 1}]
},
{
    id: 2:
    items: [{id: 'b', val: 1}, {id: 'c', val: 1}, {id: 'd', val: 1}]
}
```

Please take a look at [json representation of sample](https://gist.github.com/alexanderbeletsky/9931396).

I'd like to create query that returns array of `items`, by ids of collections, including parent collection information. My very naive in-memory approach:

```
var collectionFields = ['title', 'description', 'user', 'userData'];

db.collections.find({_id: {$in: ids}}, function (err, collections) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    }

    var items = collections.map(function (c) {
        return c.items && c.items.map(function (i) {
            return _.extend(i, {collection: _.pick(c, collectionFields)});
        });
    });

    items = items.reduce(function (memo, items) {
        if (items) {
            memo = memo.concat(items);
        }

        return memo;
    }, []);

    callback(null, {data: items, nextPage: false});
});
```

So, what it does is - selects all collections, by given array of ids. Then `map` each collection, if collection has `items` (not necessarily all does) it `map` items inside and extends each item with `collection` property, by picking up some fields from collection document (parent to items array).

As output I have something like,

```
[{ _id: 533bdaf44ad47cde5c000022,
    created: Wed Apr 02 2014 12:40:04 GMT+0300 (EEST),
    date: Wed Apr 02 2014 12:40:04 GMT+0300 (EEST),
    itemId: 7,
    user: '1396431604156@tests.com',
    userId: 533bdaf44ad47cde5c000019,
    collection:
     { title: 'collection',
       user: '1396431604156@tests.com',
       userData: [Object] } },
  { _id: 533bdaf44ad47cde5c000024,
    created: Wed Apr 02 2014 12:40:04 GMT+0300 (EEST),
    date: Wed Apr 02 2014 12:40:04 GMT+0300 (EEST),
    itemId: 9,
    user: '1396431604156@tests.com',
    userId: 533bdaf44ad47cde5c000019,
    collection:
     { title: 'collection',
       user: '1396431604156@tests.com',
       userData: [Object] } } ]
```

But I don't feel happy about. First I feel like I duplicate some native capabilities, in very inefficient way. Second, in future it will be really hard to apply additional operations like paging and sorting.

I started to think about *native* MongoDB `mapReduce`, but failed to get any good Node.js example. Moreover, I see that `aggregation` could solve it more nicely.

Would it be possible to use mapReduce/aggregation to fetch all collections by ids, take nested `items` array and produce result like example above?

**UPD:** I came up with much better solution,

```
db.collections.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {_id: {$in: ids}}
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$items'
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 0, item: '$items', collection: { _id: '$_id', title: '$title', description: '$description'} }
    },
], callback);
```

The result this query gives,

```
{ item:
     { _id: 533c3c3b6230140000000023,
       created: Wed Apr 02 2014 19:35:07 GMT+0300 (EEST),
       date: Wed Apr 02 2014 19:35:07 GMT+0300 (EEST),
       itemId: 8,
       type: 'stackoverflow',
       user: '1396456507643@tests.com',
       userId: 533c3c3b6230140000000019 },
    collection: { _id: 533c3c3b623014000000001a, title: 'collection' } },
  { item:
     { _id: 533c3c3b6230140000000024,
       created: Wed Apr 02 2014 19:35:07 GMT+0300 (EEST),
       date: Wed Apr 02 2014 19:35:07 GMT+0300 (EEST),
       itemId: 9,
       type: 'github',
       user: '1396456507643@tests.com',
       userId: 533c3c3b6230140000000019 },
    collection: { _id: 533c3c3b623014000000001a, title: 'collection' } } ]
```

Almost one I wanted, except it would be great to move `item` as top level object, as shown above.

Comment: It's a fair question, but seems to suffer a little from "impedance mismatch" in that your "sample" at the top is not even close to the "result" at the bottom. We could suggest ways if we had a more realistic sample and a corresponding result without needing to focus on how you are currently doing it. But yes this is likely mapReduce or aggregation. I just wish we had the information required to solve it.

Comment: Thx Neil, I've added json representation of collection sample to gist. Pasted link to to question.

Comment: Sure that does add some context to the question, but there is still a lot missing. For example, we can see in your `_pick` operation that you reference `collectionFields` and I have no idea what that is. Point is there is a **lot** of functionality from what you are actually doing that is missing from the question. Please find some way to add it.

Comment: I've added `collectionFields` as well as tried to explain the algorithm a bit more..

Comment: I've also updated my answer with query I created. If you help me to do a little tweek, it will be great :)